# Speech Recognizer closes when we open recorder instance in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, audio, flutter-dependencies, speech-to-text, flutter-audio-query

So I am trying to with [speech_to_text](https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text) and [flutter_sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound) plugins, So when I try to open `recorder.openRecorder();` and `speech.listen()` together, the speech.recognizer stops and throws the `ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT` error as the speech recognizer is stopped and no results were found.

[Android Errors List](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer#ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT)